# SSH: Given a public/private key pair in host generate PuTTY's Pagent necessary files

Tags: ssh, key, rsa, putty, public

I want to access to a server (hosted in Lonex) trough SSH (for file handling). For this I  use PuTTY. To do so safely, I use Pagent, it needs a public and a private key.
In the server, under the ssh folder in the root directory there are two files: 
id_rsa - which has the private key.
id_rsa.pub - which has a public key. 
Given this information, if posible, I would like to generate the necessary files for Pagent.

What I have tried:

Using PuTTYgen to import/load a local copy of the file id_rsa. This successfully generated the the .ppk file needed for Pagent. I referred to the .ppk file in connection -> ssh -> auth. In this .ppk file appears the public and the private key. But when I use PuTTY to connect, having the generated .ppk added to Pagent, an alert prompts stating that I do not have the server's host key cached in the registry and then shows the server's rsa key fingerprint, which I know to not be the right one from the one shown in Pagent. The fact that this alert prompts tells me that my Pagrent key is not correct. Am I correct?

Comments:
- Given that the host already has a public/private key pair I believe I should generate a local private key given the same public key from the host. I could not accomplished this (I read about ssh-keygen commands but I did not find out how to get what I wanted done).
- The ISP suggested that everything I need is in this link: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SSH%20keys#KeyGeneration:PuTTY 
I could not find the use to it given that I do not have a form where I should place a public key generated locally by me and also the fact that it does not consider the situation where I already have a public key generated in the host. 
- I asked the ISP if it was possible to add a public key generated locally by me to the authorized_keys2 file and they told me no due to the fact that it is a shared hosting.

Comment: It turns out to always ask for approval of confidence the first time regardless if keys are correct. According to an ex co-worker. Is this so?

Comment: The answer to your comment is yes; I've elaborated below in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question really boils down to this:

> The fact that this alert prompts tells me that my Pagrent key is not
>   correct. Am I correct?

No; this is not correct.  Your agent (Pageant) is likely set up correctly.  As you said,

> an alert prompts stating that I do not have the server's host key
>   cached in the registry and then shows the server's rsa key
>   fingerprint,

That prompt is for the server's host key, not your user's private key.  Pageant only caches your user's private key, not the host's public key (or public key fingerprint).  Pageant's purpose is to hold your private key so that the server can identify you; the purpose of the prompt that you saw was for PuTTY to allow you to verify that the server that you're connecting to is really the server you meant to connect to (i.e. that you're not connecting to an attacker's machine).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is clarifying.

Comment: If it helps, upvote.  If it answers your question, accept it as an answer.